# How to preserve facebook objects between calls in php?

Tags: php, facebook, session

I render the page corretly, display images etc. But when the user changes the album selection I want to use ajax to refresh the div.

My problem is that when I send the call to the server it gets an exception since the facebook objects are dead/no-reference, I don't know.

I tried to save them with session_start. I can pass strings like this but if I pass the objects like this than calling them still fails:

```
$albumID = $_GET['album'];
    $facebook = $_SESSION['fb'];
    $albums = $_SESSION['albums'];
    $tester = $_SESSION['tester']; //works fine
    echo get_pictures_from_album($facebook, $albums, $albumID);
```

I would also reallt appriciate it if someone can refer me to good documentation. It seems that facebook only have examples for the simple, trivial issues but no complicated apps.

Comment: Try using serialize and unserialize to store the object in a session.

Comment: I removed my answer as I misunderstood what you were trying to do until I saw @Eric Petroelje's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing an object in the session, you need to make sure you `require` the file containing the class definition before you call `session_start`.  Otherwise PHP won't be able to deserialize the objects from the session correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe that, I only did it like in my Q or with the require but tried to create a new object - Thanks!

Can you tell if what I do is good practice?

Comment: @Gal - hard for me to say as I know pretty much nothing about facebook app programming.  Just saw the line where you said "I can pass in strings but if I pass in objects..." and was pretty sure I knew what the problem was, since I've made that exact same mistake myself